# On a representation of the Moebius strip

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $f:\, (x,y,z)\in C\mapsto ((x^2-y^2)(2+xz),2xy(2+xz),yz)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. I have to prove that the image of this function is homeomorphic to the Moebius strip. I would like to use the universal property of quotient spacea, but I need to show that $f(x,y,z)=f(x',y',z',)$ if and only if $(x,y,z)=\pm(x',y',z')$. Is there any simple way to prove this? (I got lost in too many calculations).

EDIT

The domain of the map is the cylinder $C=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=1,|z|\leq1\}$.

**Definition of Moebius strip:** the quotient space $C/\sim$ where $P\sim Q\iff P=\pm Q$.

Comment: Which definition of the Möbius strip do you use? The image of $f$ is certainly unbounded, are you sure that $f$ is correctly specified?

Comment: yes, you are right the domain is the cylinder!

Comment: And what **exactly** is the definition of the Möbius strip as a quotient space?

Comment: Well, for instance one can see it as the quotient space $C/\sim$ where $P\sim Q$ if and only if $P=\pm Q$. This is actually the definition I'm using. That's why I thought I needed to show that the same happens for $f(C)$.

Comment: Okay, that is one of many possible definitions. You should add that to your question. People do not wamt to read comments to get all necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $C = S^1 \times [-1,1]$ with $S^1 = \{ w \in \mathbb C \mid \lvert w \rvert = 1\}$ . Then
$$f(w,z) = ((2+\text{Re}(w)z) w^2,\text{Im}(w)z) \in \mathbb C \times \mathbb R .$$
Therefore it is obvious that $(w,z) = - (w',z')$ implies $f(w,z) = f(w',z')$.

We have $\lvert \text{Re}(w) \lvert \le 1, \lvert z \rvert \le 1$, thus $\lvert \text{Re}(w)z \rvert \le 1$ and therefore $2+\text{Re}(w)z \ge 1 > 0$.

If $f(w,z) = f(w',z')$, then

1. $(2+\text{Re}(w)z) w^2 = (2+\text{Re}(w')z') (w')^2$
2. $\text{Im}(w)z = \text{Im}(w')z'$.

Taking the absolute value on both sides of the first equation, we get $2+\text{Re}(w)z = 2+\text{Re}(w')z'$, i.e. $\text{Re}(w)z = \text{Re}(w')z'$. Add this and $i$ times the second equation and get

3. $wz = w'z'$.

Taking the absolute value on both sides of this equation gives $\lvert z \rvert =  \lvert z' \rvert$. Thus $z  = \pm z'$. If $z \ne 0$, we immediately see from 3. that  $(w,z) = \pm (w',z')$. If $z = 0$, the first equation shows that $w^2 = (w')^2$, i.e. $w =  \pm w'$. Thus again $(w,z) = \pm (w',z')$.